# Frustrated with Rock/Paper/Scissors

Tags: c, user-defined-functions

I'm still working with my uncle on learning C, I've run into another hitch trying to compile the program we wrote together to play Rock Paper Scissors. I've still got more to do on the program but I can't even get the main bulk of the thing to work properly.

Errors I'm receiving from the compiler with the Make command

```
main.c: in function 'start_play':

main.c:79:7: error: format '%s' expects argument type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-werror=format=]

scanf("%1s", human_hand[0]);


main.c:82:11: error: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Werror=format=]

fprintf( stderr, "Player 1 has entered an invalid hand choice, %s.", player_1);

main.c:104:1: error: ISO C forbids nested functions [-Werror=pedantic]

int choice_to_int(const char a)

main.c:104:1: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=pedantic]

main.c 132:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

}

main.c:132:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

main.c:60:6: error: unused variable 'choice' [-Werror=unused-variable]

enum choices choice;
```

This is the contents of the main.c file that I can't seem to get right.

```
/*
Programmer: Tim Bowen
Creation Date: 2014/05/26
Last Updated: 2014/05/27
Project Name: RPS(Rock/Paper/Scissors)
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


int gen_hand( );
void start_play();
int choice_to_int(const char a);


int main ( int argc, char *arga[], char **env)
{    
  start_play( );    
  return 0;    
} /*end main*/


/*
Precondition: Srand must but initialized before usage of gen_hand
Post condition: function returns either 0, 1 or 2.
*/ 


int gen_hand( ) {
  return((rand() % 3 ));
}

void start_play( ) {

  enum choices { ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS };
  enum choices choice;
  const char *rps[] = {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"};
  int player_1, player_2;
  char answer[2];
  char human_hand[2];
  srand(time(NULL));

  printf("%s\n", "This program plays Rock, Paper, Scissors.");
  printf("%s\n", "Version 0.2");

  do{
    printf("%s\n", "Do you want to play against the computer? (Y/N):");
    printf("%s\n", "Any other character to quit.:");
    scanf("%1s", answer);
    printf("%s\n", answer);
    break;
    if(answer[0] == 'y' || answer[0] == 'Y')
    {
      printf( "%s\n", "Please enter your hand(R/P/S):");
      scanf("%1s", human_hand[0]);
      player_1=choice_to_int(human_hand[0]);
        if(player_1==3){
          fprintf( stderr, "Player 1 entered an invalid hand choice, %s", player_1 );
/*          err_hand();
          break;} */
      player_2=gen_hand( );
      printf( "Player one => %d\n %2s", player_1, rps[player_1]);
      printf( "player two => %d\n %2s", player_2, rps[player_2]);
    }
    else if (answer[0] == 'n' || answer[0] == 'N' )
    { 
      player_1=gen_hand( );
      player_2=gen_hand( );
      printf( "Player one => %d\n %2s", player_1, rps[player_1]);
      printf( "player two => %d\n %2s", player_2, rps[player_2]);
    }
    else {
      break;     
    }
  while (1);
  return;

}


/*
precondition: user passes in either, Rr, Pp, Ss, or another incorrect response.
post condition: function returns either 0, 1, or 2 for correct responses, or 3 for erroneous ones.
*/


int choice_to_int(const char a) 
  {

  int r;

  switch ( r ) {

    case 'R':
    case 'r':
    r=0;
    break;

    case 'P':
    case 'p':
    r=1;
    break;

    case 'S':
    case 's':
    r=2;
    break;

    default:
    r=3;
    break;

 }
return (r); 
}
```

I apologize for the nearly excessive number of extra lines but I did that so that it could be (hopefully) more easily read. I'm not sure what I've done wrong this time since I almost completely copied this from the notes I took from class. I can't move on to trying to add in the sections I'm supposed to because I can't get the part that we coded together to even work properly. None of these errors came up in the example when my uncle compiled it.

**Edit:** So far the answers given have helped to clear up most of the errors that are involved, except for a new error:

> main.c:58:5 error: format '%s' expected arguments of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[2]' [-Werror=format]

It's still complaining as well that I'm not using the variable 'choice' but to be honest, I'm not sure how to use choice. 
I may not have been clear on this, but I didn't directly 'write' this. I suggested while my uncle wrote, then I rewrote it on my machine after 'class' was over. I don't really claim to entirely understand what I'm doing here... The program should be obvious(to someone with lots of experience coding...) but I guess I'm not getting it.

It's supposed to take the option of playing rock/paper/scissors, and give the option to have the computer play with itself(the else if statement), we were using enum to designate the choices, then choice_to_int to take the user input and translate it back into the values that would match enum and allow me to create the 'win/lose/draw' statement based on the comparison of those. I probably suggested some silly methods to implement this idea, but that's the idea. I have still not gotten to the point where I can create the win/lose/draw statement, or handle the error if the user decides to put in something that doesn't fit the games format (Say, Z or something).

Thank you for your help thus far and bearing with me on this, perhaps, unnecessarily complex implementation of rock/paper/scissors...

Comment: Best title I've seen in a while.

Comment: Checked your profile, says you're a writer. Just curious, if you do not plan to program on somewhat low level, why C :)?

Comment: @Andro47
I thought it's sort of a three fold answer, firstly, most writers don't make a living writing, atleast not to start, secondly, the fiction I write, I would eventually like to branch into franchise work such as games and such, so learning to code C and other languages would assist in my ability to work with whoever was directly handling that aspect, the third part is that it wasn't entirely my idea. I asked my uncle to teach me to code, and this is what he thought was best. 
So far I'm finding it hard to understand...

Comment: It's a shame I can't checkmark multiple answers, because several answers helped clear up the initial errors, but I still haven't gotten it entirely working yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some general advice: instead of writing 100 lines of code with dozens of problems, just write a small piece at a time, check that it all works correctly, and then move onto the next piece.

Problems that haven't been mentioned yet by other answers:

---

```
int gen_hand( );
void start_play();
```

should be:

```
int gen_hand(void);
void start_play(void);
```

The `void` means that the function takes no parameters; the empty parentheses mean that we don't know how many it takes yet (and your program may screw up if you don't get it right).

---

Next, `scanf("%1s", answer);` and `scanf("%1s", human_hand[0]);`. With `scanf` you have to tell it where to write the characters you read.  Instead you are telling it the current values of those things. Use the `&` operator to take the address of the destination location.

---

In this code:

```
if(player_1==3){
  fprintf( stderr, "Player 1 entered an invalid hand choice, %s", player_1 );
/*          err_hand();
      break;} */
```

you never close the `{` because you commented out the closing `}`. You should not comment out the `break;}` because it means you go on to use `3` as an array index which is out of bounds.

---

In `printf( "player two => %d\n %2s", player_2, rps[player_2]);`, the `2` means: print at least 2 characters. All of your strings are much longer than 2 , so this has no effect. What were you trying to do?

Comment: The %2s, as far as I knew from what my uncle said, placing 2 at the beginning of the s would move the characters you're asking it to print over by 2 spaces, though I may have misunderstood.

Comment: The 2 is the *minimum field width*. It means that if your string is shorter than 2, then it will print 2 characters still (left-padding with spaces). However if your string is longer than 2 then this makes no difference.  If you want to print 2 spaces then just put two spaces before the `%`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at C but probably this string

```
fprintf( stderr, "Player 1 entered an invalid hand choice, %s", player_1 );
```

should be

```
fprintf( stderr, "Player 1 entered an invalid hand choice, %d", player_1 );
```

And you need to changed all the strings where the variable is int to %d.

You forgot a closing bracket:

```
if(player_1==3){
      fprintf( stderr, "Player 1 entered an invalid hand choice, %s", player_1 );
}
```

And error `main.c:104:1: error: ISO C forbids nested functions [-Werror=pedantic] int choice_to_int(const char a)` is also related to missing bracket as the compiler thinks it is still in previous function (start_play())

Answer (score 0):

Besides what has already been said:

Well looking at this:

```
int choice_to_int(const char a) 
{
   int r;
   switch ( r ) {  ... }
  /* .... */
}
```

You are switching on an uninitialised variable! Remove `int r;` and change the function to
`int choice_to_int(const char r) {...}`  You also forgot to properly close function (missing '}')

```
void start_play( )
```

Comment: true, he should have 'return' statements instead of assignments.